# React-Native app close immediately on Android

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am trying to open my *react-native application*, however it closes immediately after opening.
It simply closes without accusing any error in cmd or in the application itself.

NODE -V: 13.9.0
REACT-NATIVE -V: 2.0.1
YARN -V: 1.22.0

---

16GB RAM
INTEL I7 8th Gen
SSD

Comment: Did you install react-navigation?

Comment: If you're having trouble with your code, posting the code might be helpful.

Comment: This might happen after you add some package (like react-navigation) without changing the gradle file according to the related documentation. Please recheck the gradle files.